# Is there a database of time zone lines available for download?

Tags: geolocation, timezone, standards, coordinates, latitude-longitude

I've searched and found a [couple](http://www.earthtools.org/webservices.htm#timezone) [of](http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html#timezone) online web services that do this, but I was wondering it there's a database in the public domain which gives a list of latitudes and longitudes for the standard time zone lines? I'd like to be able to calculate what time zone a coordinate is without using a web service. I figured that time zone boundaries are mostly static and were probably decided by some committee, so there should be a CSV or GPX or KML somewhere.

I'd like to be able to check what time zone a coordinate lies in, for example:

48.856667 2.350833 is GMT+1 or CET

Answer (score 2):

This is a series of files -- timezone polygons (shapefile), which you can transform into boundaries. With work on your part.

```
http://efele.net/maps/tz/world/
```

You should note that simply knowing the TZ does not guarantee that you know anything about the current correct time or date there in terms of the local calendar. Time Ex: The Isreali Knesset (parliament) decides when Daylight time starts and ends - sometimes they have chosen a date in the past.  Date Ex: The Hijri Calendar changes months based on the ability of people in Mecca to actually observe the new moon from there.   Cloudy days alter the date.

Answer (score 0):

[Askgeo.com](http://www.askgeo.com) has a Java library under commercial license. (Scroll down their page to find information about it). They charge 2 grand up front for it though, considering the amount of work they must have put in compiling loads of vector maps, etc, I can understand they want the money.

I use their free API, but you wanted something downloadable, and I think this is one of your few bets.

Comment: Actually, that site has nothing downloadable in terms of a time zone boundary database.

Comment: I see, so the Java library calls a remote site? I supposed that it included the actual data.

Comment: No, the Java library uses a locally stored "spatial index", which is optimized for lookup performance.  That site doesn't make available anything similar to a list of time zone boundaries in the form of a text file or XML file.

Answer (score 0):

I tried openstreetmap and they have the data, but it would be buried in a map of Earth, not completely useful itself. Here is one on Wikipedia though: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Answer (score 0):

I recently found this data here:
https://github.com/straup/whereonearth-timezone